# Impress.js: CSS3 select one id within another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if this is possible in CSS3. I am using impress.js and was wondering if i could trigger a transform after it changes the class of a div.

```
#slide-4.step.active {  
#logo img {
transform: scaleX(-1);
}
}
```

Slide-4 is about to become active it is given the class active. I was wondering if i could access another image in another div to transform it to flip it around. Was curious if i could select another div within a div selector

Answer (score 0):

If the div is a child div I think this is completely do-able, with something like:

```
#slide-4.step.active > #logo img { transform:scaleX(-1); }
```

Usually, if you need interactivity outside of a simple nav menu, try to write the behavior in jQuery; most of the work is already done for you!  It would look something like this in jQuery (i'm using brief pseudocode, don't try and copy/paste):

```
$('#slide-4.step.active').change(function(){ 
  $('#logo img').transform(-1,0);
});
```

Comment: No; you should use CSS where possible.  And you want a descendent selector.

Comment: how is OP supposed to use descendent selectors (which are pretty much just wildcards) access the div that may or may not be a child in CSS?  The issue was that an action of some div (maybe not a child) needs to be triggered after some other div gets a change in class.